Proof that Work Done by Kinetic Friction is independent of the Reference Frame
In classical (non relativistic) mechanics, is the work done by Kinetic Friction independent from the reference frame? If so, how could we prove it?

What kind of friction, static or kinetic?

Kinetic, sorry. Isn't the work done by static friction always zero?

No. The work done by static friction is not always zero.

Let the intensity of friction force between two bodies be $F_{12}$,
$$F_{12} = \mu N $$
with $\mu$ the friction coefficient and $N \ge 0$ the normal reaction between the bodies. Let's call $\mathbf{F}_{12}$ force acting on body $1$ due to body $2$, and $\mathbf{F}_{21} = -\mathbf{F}_{12}$ the force acting on $2$ due to $1$, is "equal and opposite" due to Newton's 3rd law (action & reaction).
Let's evaluate the power of friction, namely:
$$\begin{aligned}
P & = \mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{F}_{21} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 \\
& = \mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot \left( \mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_2 \right)  \\
& = \mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{v}_{1/2} \ 
\end{aligned}$$
i.e. the power of the friction is the scalar product of the force and the relative velocity of the bodies; the scalar product of two vectors is independent from rotation of the reference frame; the relative velocity of 2 bodies is independent from the reference frame as well; thus the power of friction is independent from the reference frame.
You can also take a look at the answer here, for the proof that this power is non-positive, being: $$\mathbf{F}_{12} = - \mu N \frac{\mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_2}{|\mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_2|} = -\mu N \frac{\mathbf{v}_{1/2}}{|\mathbf{v}_{1/2}|}$$
and thus: $$P = - \mu N |\mathbf{v}_{1/2}| \le 0$$

Friction always involves two objects. The work done by kinetic friction on either object is not the same in all reference frames in Newtonian mechanics. However, the total mechanical energy lost from both objects together is the same in all frames.
The proof is easiest in terms of power. Once it is proven for power then the proof for work is just an integral.
Given two objects of mass $M$ and $m$ with velocities $v_m=v_M+v_r$. This means that $m$ is slipping in the positive direction along $M$ with a slipping speed of $v_r$. The kinetic friction force on $M$ is $F$ and the friction force on $m$ is $-F$. The mechanical power entering $M$ is $$P_M=F\cdot v_M$$ and the mechanical power entering $m$ is $$P_m=-F\cdot v_m = -F \cdot v_M - F\cdot v_r$$ Note that both of these depend on the reference frame as $v_M$ depends on the reference frame. The total mechanical power entering the system is $$P_M+P_m = F \cdot v_M-F \cdot v_M - F\cdot v_r = - F\cdot v_r$$ Note that this is negative, meaning mechanical power is being lost, and note that it depends only on $v_r$ so it is independent of the reference frame.

Explain how the measurable results of kinetic friction work is the same in all frames while the friction work itself is not.

I’m assuming we can consider kinetic friction is independent of velocity

@BobD you replied while I was still writing the answer. Hopefully it is clear now.

It is clear +1. Unique thing about kinetic friction work is it’s negative for both objects

@BobD not necessarily. Only the sum is necessarily negative, but either one individually can be positive in some reference frame

Kinetic friction work raises the temperature of the materials at the contacting surfaces of both of the objects involved,  subsequently generating heat. Temperature and heat are reference frame independent. Therefore consequences of kinetic friction work on the two objects are reference frame independent.
Hope this helps.

I was curious how temperature would be measured of a moving reference frame. If the temperature is measured optically, would that measurement be frame dependent?

@StevanV.Saban were talking newtonian mechanics involving non relativistic velocities. So we can, for example, use infrared thermometers

This suggests that the loss from friction is independent of the reference frame.   But the "work done by friction" may take other forms (such as changing the KE of the contacted object)

@BobD Temperature is definitely not frame independent.T = 2/kN where k is Boltzmann's constant and N is the degrees of freedom.Since K~u^2 the relationship between kinetic energy and velocity is non-linear which means that if you switch reference frames the average value of kinetic energy changes hence the temperature.

@RootGroves I have never heard of temperature being reference frame dependent, at least for non relativistic velocities . Can you cite any authoritative references?

http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/temperature_rel.pdf

@RootGroves why are you giving me this. I already said we’re talking about non relativistic newtonian mechanics

"Friction work raises the temperature of the materials, subsequently generating heat." Isn't it the other way around? Friction work is converted to heat, which might raise the temperature of the materials?
If the friction happens on ice at 0° C, it could melt the ice, which would still be at 0° C.

@RootGroves No. Heat in thermodynamics is defined as the transfer of energy due solely to temperature difference. Friction is work not heat. For example, when you rub your hands vigorously together to warm them up on a cold day the temperature of the epidermis of your hands increases due to the rubbing action (friction work) not a temperature difference.  Then  heat flows from the elevated epidermis temperature to the dermis below where you sense temperature, Contrast that with warming your hands by an open fire, where your skin temperature rises due temperature difference.

Regarding your ice example, the energy transferred to the ice by friction work causes a phase change instead of a temperature increase. The amount of energy transferred by friction work is equivalent to the transfer of latent heat due to temperature difference between the heat source and the ice

So in reality the word “heating” in “friction heating” refers to the result of raising the temperature of something (supplying the energy for a phase change ) rather then the mechanism involved with raising the temperature of something (mechanism for causing the phase change), which is work, in this case friction work.

@BobD you realise molecules move at relativistic speeds right?Anyway im not going to argue any more the scientific community has said that relativistic temperature is meaningless so it doesnt matter at all.

@RootGroves Really. I thought it was about 500 m/s. See: https://www.hunter.cuny.edu/physics/courses/physics110/repository/files/section51/15TheKineticTheoryofGasesRev2.pdf Far less than the speed of light, about 300 x 10$^6$ m/s.

Consider two equal and opposite forces acting on an object. Choose a reference frame in which the object is stationary. In this frame the work done by each force is zero. Now choose a reference frame in which the object has a constant velocity in the direction of either force. In this frame the work done by each force is non-zero (although the total work done by both forces is still zero).
Since we see that the work done by any force is frame dependent, the work done by kinetic friction is certainly frame dependent.
